# how to get a particular field from a database via php

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I am trying to get four different values from my database.  The session variable `username` and `usernameto` are working, but I want to get 4 different values -- two each from username and usernameto:

```
<?php
    session_start(); // startsession

    $Username=$_SESSION['UserID'];
    $Usernameto= $_SESSION['UserTO'];



    $db = mysql_connect("at-web2.xxxxxx", "yyyyy", "xxxxxxx");
    mysql_select_db("db_xxxxxx",$db);

    $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT user_lon and user_lat FROM table1 WHERE id = '$Usernameto'");
    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT user_lon and user_lat FROM table1 WHERE id = '$Username'");

    $myrow1 = mysql_fetch_row($result1);
    $myrow2 = mysql_fetch_row($result2);


    while($myrow1)
    {
        $_Mylon=$myrow1[0];
        $_Mylat=$myrow1[1];
    }
    while($myrow2)
    {
        $_Mylon2=$myrow2[0];
        $_Mylat2=$myrow2[1];
    }
?>
```

Comment: Don't post your mysql_connect username & password on the internet - I've edited to obscure these.

Comment: Although it is still visible in edit history, so it would maybe be better to delete this whole question and post it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit - just realized that you didn't tell us what wasn't working about the code you provided.  Are you getting an error message or are you not getting the correct data back?  You still should fix your query, but we'll need some more information to know what's wrong.

Your query statements shouldn't have "and" between the select parameters, so it should be:

Edit 2 - I just noticed that you had a while loop that you don't need, try this:

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT user_lon, user_lat FROM table1 WHERE id = '$Usernameto'");
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT user_lon, user_lat FROM table1 WHERE id = '$Username'");

$myrow1 = mysql_fetch_row($result1);
$myrow2 = mysql_fetch_row($result2);

if (isset($myrow1)) {
    $_Mylon=$myrow1[0];
    $_Mylat=$myrow1[1];
}

if (isset($myrow2)) {
    $_Mylon2=$myrow2[0];
    $_Mylat2=$myrow2[1];
}
```

Comment: ok i adjusted the code and i tried to echo the result but it didnt bring out the value in the database

Answer (score 0):

[An example from the php manual echoing an html table](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.examples-basic.php)

I don't know if you can derive what you need from this?

More specific: You can use:

```
$line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

Comment: i think its possible, i just dont know how to do it